# Why my GPU fans RPM is a sine wave when idle?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, fan

I've a Gainward GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER Phoenix V1 8GB GDDR6 and I'm quite worried about the RPM of fans which tend to go in sine wave. Is it something I should be worried about? Can I make it stop or should I?

Here it is how it looks, notice the bottom charts with RPM. Screen below was taken from MSI Afterburner with 100ms interval (just for making clear sin wave screenshot, I don't keep it to refresh that often normally)

[image]

For fan control I use Palit ThunderMaster, during summer I moved from Palit GTX 1060 6GB, so that's why Palit's software with Gainward GPU. It just does the job even for different GPU, so I didn't see it as necessary to uninstall it only because the GPU changed.

[image]

Sorry for options in my native language, the options are:

- [ ] Constant speed
- [ ] Default speed curve
- [x] Defined speed curve

With such defined speed curve, the GPU rarely goes up to 80 degrees Celsius. If it does, it is usually a demanding video game like Red Dead Redemption 2, which is justified.

I have latest Nvidia drivers v456.71, running on Windows 10 Pro N. The card have three fans. I can provide other specs if necessary.

EDIT:

Additional screens with various interval:

200 ms:

[image]

500 ms:

[image]

1000 ms:

[image]

Comment: if you change the polling time to 200ms, does the wavelength change (or double)?

Comment: @Yorik I've updated the question, see additional screens.